# Why does the tuple() function in python return to many parentheses

Tags: python, string, python-2.7, tuples

To be clear, I'm trying to convert a tuple to string, and then convert the string back to a tuple without any changes like an extra parenthese.

When I use this

```
#Creates and prints an tuple
tuple_list = (480L, 640L, 3L)
print tuple_list
```

it prints `(480L, 640L, 3L)`

But when I use

```
#Converts the tuple to string and then prints the tuple form of the string
stri = str(tuple_list)
print tuple([stri])
```

it prints `('(480L, 640L, 3L)',)`

Why doesn't this print `(480L, 640L, 3L)`, and how do I make it print this?

Comment: Because the latter is a tuple of 3 long integers, and the former is a tuple containing one string.

Comment: @meowgoesthedog I made a mistake in my quistion, but I updated it? Is the awsner still the same? and if so how do I make it print my desired outcome

Comment: Just `print stri`. When you try to print a non-string object, string conversion is done implicitly anyway.

Comment: @meowgoesthedog No, I need the tuple form. I have a program that automaticly converts it to string and I need the tuple form, but if I try to convert it back, I get this problem. Please help me get me my desired outcome

Comment: Then you should edit your question to make it clear that your goal is to **convert a string back to a tuple**.

Comment: @meowgoesthedog I edited the quistion, is this better?

Comment: You should edit your title too because that's the first thing other users read.

Comment: Why do you want to do what you say you want to do? The round-trip of tuple to single string back to tuple seems to be not the best algorithm... That might help us figure out a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This:

```
stri = str(tuple_list)
print tuple([stri])
```

first creates a string representation of `tuple_list`, then creates a list containing this string as single element, then build a `tuple` (with the same string as single element) from this list, and finally prints the representation of this tuple. If you break it down, this is doing (`print` statements added at each step to make things clearer):

```
stri = str(tuple_list)
print("stri: '{}'".format(repr(stri)))
lst = [stri]
print("lst: '{}'".format(repr(lst)))
tup = tuple(lst)
print("tup: '{}'".format(repr(tup)))
print(tup)
```

> I need the tuple form, but if I try to convert it back, I get this problem.

You want `ast.literal_eval()` then:

```
>>> import ast
>>> tup = ("a", "b", "c")
>>> stri = str(tup)
>>> stri
"('a', 'b', 'c')"
>>> result = ast.literal_eval(stri)
>>> result
('a', 'b', 'c')
```

NB: note that this will only work for tuples containing literals constants.

As a side note: when using `print` to inspect objects, use `print repr(obj)`, not `print obj`, so you get the proper internal representation of the object.

Comment: `NameError: name 'ast' is not defined`

Answer (score 0):

Then just do this:

```
`print(stri)`
```

To then later convert this string to tuple you'll have to use the module literal eval like this :

`from ast import literal_eval`

`print(literal_eval(stri))`

Comment: Oops, made a fault in my quistion I want to print the tuple form of stri, I edited my quistion so please edit your awsner

Comment: Check now! @hetijav

Comment: @meowgoesthedog please do NOT advice using `eval` - it's highly unsafe, specially when, obviously, the string to eval comes from the outside world. The proper solution here is `ast.literal_eval()`, which is mostly safe.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers, The awnser he gave me works, and `ast.literal_eval()` gave me `NameError: name 'ast' is not defined`

Comment: @hetijav like all modules, `ast` has to imported. And while it "works", `eval` will unconditionnally execute whatever you pass it, which is a sure way to make your code opened to script-kiddies. There are actually _very very_ few cases where there isn't a better solution than `eval` (actually I have yet to find one...)

Answer (score 0):

This line:

```
print tuple_list
```

turns the tuple into a string representation and presents it on the screen.

```
(480L, 640L, 3L)
```

If you print the string literal "(400", like this: `print "(400"` then you will see

```
(480
```

on the screen. Likewise, the string representation of the tuple `(480L, 640L, 3L)` is the string `"(480L, 640L, 3L)"`.

This line:

```
stri = str(tuple_list)
```

also creates a string representation of `(480L, 640L, 3L)` and stores it in the variable `stri`. If at that point you do `print stri` you will get the same output as the original. But then your code does this:

```
print tuple([stri])
```

That does three things in one line. First, it creates a list of one element `[stri]`. Then it calls `tuple()` which turns the 1-element list into a 1-element tuple `(stri,)`. Finally, it calls `print` which turns your 1-element tuple into a string representation of that tuple: `"('(480L, 640L, 3L)',)"` and prints it. That answers the first part of your question.

It's clear that you are expecting `stri = str(tuple_list)` to do something other than it does. But it is not clear from your question what output you are expecting. The question says "`(480L, 640L, 3L):` how do I make it print this?" but you already know the answer to that because that is the output from `print tuple_list` as your question says. So what output do you really expect?

Comment: I cant use tuple_list anymore in the program I'm creating, the only thing I can use is stri.

Comment: Then `print` it without the complicated transformations.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to change the element type as string.

```
tuple(map(str, a))
```

Answer (score -1):

You're not being completely clear about what you want. What do you think `stri = str(tuple_list)` does? I suspect what you want is to convert each element of the tuple *separately* into a string:

```
>>> stri = tuple(str(element) for element in tuple_list)
```

This then gives the tuple that I think you want:

```
>>> print stri

('480', '640', '3')
```

(Note also that you are using what I think is the Python 2.x syntax for long integers which is probably not necessary. You are probably learning Python from a quite old resource.)

(Your version converts the entire tuple into a single string.)